# AVCaptureSession Pausing Session

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation, avcapturesession

When I want to pause the session, this was the only solution for me:

```
func pauseSession () {
            self.sessionQueue.async {
                if self.session.isRunning {
                     self.session.stopRunning()
                }
            }
    }

func resumeSession () {
            self.sessionQueue.async {
                if !self.session.isRunning {
                    self.session.startRunning()
                }
            }
}
```

This seems to completely stop the session, which is fine, yet looks expensive.

The issue I seem to have is if pause and resume are called near each other in time, the whole app freezes for about 10 seconds, till going back to being responsive. This is mostly due to it still hasn't finished the last process (whether to stop or start).

Is there a solution to this?

The native camera app seems to do this fine. If you open it, open the last photo, you can see the green indicator on the top right going off, meaning the session has paused/stopped. If you swipe down on the photo, the session resumes.  If you swipe and let it get canceled, quickly swipe again you can see the session pauses and resumes quickly over and over without any issues.

Comment: Have you checked how it behaves in release builds without a debugger attached?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to change `async` to `sync`

```
self.sessionQueue.sync {
```

Comment: Wouldn’t that block the main queue.

Comment: it will serialize `sessionQueue`  no effect on main queue

Comment: It actually freezes the UI for few seconds when starting AND stopping.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession mentions: The startRunning() method is a blocking call which can take some time, therefore you should perform session setup on a serial queue so that the main queue isn’t blocked (which keeps the UI responsive).